# Encode Data to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, utf-8

I am getting an encoding error from an XML file generated from a XMLWriter. However I am sure that I can fix this error by converting the data from whatever encoding it is at the moment to UTF-8 encoding.

I would be greatful if you could tell me how to do this.

The error is

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 721: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

The code on line 2 at column 721 is `<street>Mall CafÈ</street>`.

My code to do this is:

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("stores.xml");
$xml->startDocument("1.0");
$xml->startElement("stores");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$xml->startElement("store");
  $xml->startElement("type");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['type']);

  $xml->endElement();

 $xml->startElement("name");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['name']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("street");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['street']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("address1");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['address1']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("address2");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['address2']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("county");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['county']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("postcode");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['postcode']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("number");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['number']);

  $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("latlong");

  $xml->writeRaw($row['latlong']);

  $xml->endElement();
  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();
header ("Content-Type: text/xml");
$xml->flush();
?>
```

Comment: Please show some code and the actual error messages

Comment: At which point does the error occur? With what character?

Comment: it occurs once the xml file has been made and I load it in my web browser. It occurs after the third name tag

Comment: But *what character* causes the error exactly?

Comment: I don't know. Is there a way I could find out?

Comment: @XcodeDev looking in `line 2 at column 721` should give you the character in question.

Comment: Ok obviously, but how could I view line 2 at column 721? Im not sure how I could get that information.

Comment: Who is giving you the error, XMLWriter?

Comment: no, the actual XML file that has been created by XMLWriter.

Comment: Who is giving you the error then?

Comment: my webhost when I try to open the XML file in my browser.

Comment: If it's a XML source file, you should be able to get the code in the browser somehow. Try "view source"

Comment: `<parsererror xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 2 at column 721: Encoding error</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror>`

Comment: Can you download the file through FTP?

Comment: The XML file generated by PHP? That should be complete an intact. What does it contain at line 2 column 721?

Comment: How can I find out what the line number and column number are in a text editor/ide program?

Comment: @Xcode an editor like Notepad++ should be able to show it.

Comment: Line 2 Column 721 is this: `<street>Mall CafÈ</street>`

Comment: @XCode I have to run now so I can't continue, but do edit that code into your question, and add some information about where the data comes  from (a database? Some other source?) so you can find out the correct encoding. You *will* need to know the source encoding to do a proper conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $writer->startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
```